# Does SQL Server have a Date_Format function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, date-format

All I found is a list of predefined `DateFormat` that I can choose from, like [this](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

As I remember in MySQL (and PostgeSQL too?) you can define your Date Format:

```sql
DATE_FORMAT(now(),'&m_%Y') --for 02_2012 etc.
```

Does SQL Server have the same thing? I see people have to write a function to do such thing, does it have a built-in one?

---

EDIT:

I just found the `DatePart` function. It can take Month as number, but always returns 1 digit, even I use  `datePart(MM, getdate())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202257/is-there-a-way-to-get-dates-with-custom-formats-in-sql-server

Comment: Typically, formatting should be handled by the client, not the database.  That being said, if you must format the database output, Martin Smith has already provided options.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not yet.

You need to use `CONVERT` with a style parameter or hack something together with [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) or [`DATENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx).

SQL Server 2012 will have the [`FORMAT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28SQL.110%29.aspx) function though that accepts a .NET Framework format string

Syntax:

```
FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )
```

Example Usage

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US' )
```

You could always use CLR integration and create your own UDF that does the same thing for 2005 or 2008.

Comment: Ahhh, 2012! Oh well, I guess I will write a UDF like you said.  Thanks

Comment: That will be awesome.

Comment: @KingChan and Martin: Regarding the use of SQLCLR to accomplish this in SQL Server 2005 / 2008 / 2008 R2, there is always the option of downloading the Free version of [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) (which I am the author of, but **Date_Format** is free) and then there is no need to do any coding. I have a few examples of both `SQL#.Date_Format` and the built-in `FORMAT` on this S.O. answer: [Is there a way to get dates with custom formats in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34996390/577765) :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simply formatted output and it doesn't need to remain in the datetime datatype, using CONVERT with a format code is an excellent tool.  A list of formats and their respective codes can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx